# How can I set arrow markers to rotate in Plotly for R?

Tags: r, plotly

Trying to create a plot similar to [this Windy plot](https://i.imgur.com/00lBocF.png), simply showing a rotated arrow marker based on my dataset which contains datetime (datawx_df$obsTime) and wind directions 0-360, (datawx_df$wdir).

My arrows print at the right x datetime, but they don't rotate, even if I manually change the angle to a number like 10, [it still points down](https://i.imgur.com/CLC8N9C.png). I'm using Plotly 4.10.3 to add the trace to an existing time series scatter plot:

```
fig <- fig %>%
      add_trace(
        x = datawx_df$obsTime,
        y = 35,
        marker = list(
          symbol = 'triangle-down-open',
          size = 10,
          angle = datawx_df$wdir,
          color = 'red'
        ),
        mode = 'markers',
        name = 'Wind Direction',
        yaxis = 'y2',
        visible = 'legendonly'
      )
```

I'm also aware that angle needs to be -180 to 180 possibly, but first I want to verify I can rotate at all.

Answer (score 0):

In this answer, I've created some data to show how this works and why. If you have any questions, let me know.

> If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample data like the output from `dput()` or `reprex::reprex()` and any libraries you are using. Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).

The main reason you're not seeing rotation: R's Plotly is still using version 2.11. Plotly's current version is 2.27. You don't need that version to make it work, but you do need something more recent than 2.11.

In my example, I've arbitrarily chosen version 2.21.

Using the library `htmltools`, I created the new dependency.

```
library(plotly)
library(htmltools)

newDep <- htmlDependency(name = "plotly-latest",
                         version = "2.21.1",               # "2.11.1"
                         src = list(href = "https://cdn.plot.ly"),
                         script = "plotly-2.21.0.min.js")  # "plotly-2.11.1.min.js"
```

For my plot, here's the data I created.

```
df1 <- data.frame(Hours = 1:10,
                  Temp = 50:59,
                  Wind = seq(30, by = 30, length.out = 10))
```

While Plotly does require degrees (versus radians), you're not confined to -180 to 180.

I also want to point out that I used `triangle-right-open`, because I wanted 0 degrees to point to 0 degrees per the unit circle.

To add the dependency, you can create a plot object and add it after. However, here I've used a UDF to add the dependency as the plot is created.

> NOTE: If you are using `Shiny`, this method of adding dependencies won't work.

```
addDep <- function(plt) {   # UDF to add the new dependency
  plt$dependencies <- append(plt$dependencies, list(newDep))
  plt
}

plot_ly(type = "scatter", mode = "markers", df1, x = ~Hours, y = ~Temp,
        marker = list(symbol = "triangle-right-open", size = 10, 
                      angle = df1$Wind, color = "red")) %>% addDep() # <<-- call UDF
```

[image]